# Importing multiple javascript files to html using Bottle that are in subfolder of javascript folder

Tags: javascript, html, bottle

I have an **html** that needs multiple javascript files in order to work. They all need to be imported using javascript function *importModules*. This is a function in another javascript file that has routes to all the modules that are needed. The **html** file works fine if when I open it up in web browser. However when I tried to use Bottle, it doesn't upload those libraries. The root tree looks something like this:

```
\---javascript
    |   something1.js
    |   something2.js
    \---_libraries
        \---lib1
            |   one.js
            |   two.js
            |  
            +---lib1.1
            |       three.js
            |       four.js
            |       
            +---lib1.2
            |   +---lib1.2.1
            |   |       five.js
            |   |       six.js
            |   |       seven.js
            |   |       
            |   +---lib1.2.2
            |   |       eight.js
            |   |       
            |   +---lib1.2.3
            |   |       nine.js
            |   |       
            |   +---lib1.2.4
            |   |       ten.js
            ...
```

The important is only what lies inside the folder of libraries (This is just a small fraction of them). And I need all the files in every folder. Most of them are **js** and some are **css**.

I have copied libraries into *javascript* folder in Bottle and I routed each of them by hand, but with no success. Like this:

```py
#lib1 js
@bottle.route('../static/javascript/libraries/lib1/<filename:re:.*\.js>')
def send_lib1(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='../static/javascript/libraries/lib1')
```

I did this for all the files. However it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any solution? And maybe how can I simplify this so I don't have to write everything by hand.

ChatGPT suggested this:

```py
@bottle.route('/static/javascript/<filepath:path>')
def send_javascript(filepath):
    return bottle.static_file(filepath, root='./javascript')
```

But it doesn't work.